# Getting 400 response in Gatling After Mapping whereas same service works correctly in SOAP UI

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I am trying to map a working soap request to Gatling seems very basic but i keep getting 400 error in Gatling whereas i am getting 200 OK in SOAP UI

Here is SOAP UI details :-

```
Raw-->
POST http://r21sVCS.onlinegaming.local:4059/Business/EventReporterV2 
HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "http://www.ds.com/Service/2013- 
03/IEventReporterEndpoint/GetAccountVersion"
Content-Length: 385
Host: r20services.onlinegaming.local:4059
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

XML-->
   <soapenv:Envelope 
   xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
   xmlns:ns="http://www.ds.com/Service/2013-03">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
     <ns:GetAccountVersion>
       <!--Optional:-->
       <ns:request>
          <ns:UserName>?</ns:UserName>
       </ns:request>
      </ns:GetAccountVersion>
    </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now the equivalent Gatling code is :-
   package simulations

```
import baseConfig.BaseSimulation
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._

import scala.language.postfixOps

class ERBSGetServiceVersion extends BaseSimulation {


val httpProtocol = http 
.baseURL("http://r21sVCS.onlinegaming.local:4059/Business/
EventReporterV2")

val header = Map(
"POST" -> "http://r21sVCS.onlinegaming.local:4059/Business/EventReporterV2 
HTTP/1.1",
"Accept-Encoding" -> "gzip,deflate",
"Content-Type" -> "text/xml;charset=UTF-8",
"SOAPAction" -> "http://www.ds.com/Service/2013- 
03/IEventReporterEndpoint/GetAccountVersion",
"Content-Length" -> "385",
"Host" -> "r21sVCS.onlinegaming.local:4059",
"Connection" -> "Keep-Alive",
"User-Agent" -> "Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)"
    )






val scn = scenario("SOAPRecordedSimulation")
  .exec(http("Get Service Soap Request")
    .post(" HTTP/1.1")
    .headers(header)
    .body(StringBody("""<soapenv:Envelope 
 xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
 xmlns:ns="http://www.ds.com/Service/2013-03">
                     |   <soapenv:Header/>
                     |   <soapenv:Body>
                     |      <ns:GetAccountVersion>
                     |         <!--Optional:-->
                     |         <ns:request>
                     |            <ns:UserName>?</ns:UserName>
                     |         </ns:request>
                     |      </ns:GetAccountVersion>
                     |   </soapenv:Body>
                     |</soapenv:Envelope>""")))
  setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1))).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

Kindly Note this service doesnt requires authentication but still Gatling 
throws 400

```
17:11:56.245 [WARN ] i.g.h.a.ResponseProcessor - Request 'Get Service Soap 
Request' failed: 
status.find.in(200,304,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209), but actually 
found 400

---- Errors -------------------------------------------------------------- 
------
> status.find.in(200,304,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209), b      1 
(100.0%)
but actually found 400
```

Comment: I think you might need to ".stripMargin" at the end of your StringBody with the xml payload

Comment: tried it now no success

Answer (score 0):

Just use ELFFileBody solved my problem,i put contents of SOAP envelope in .txt file and kept in resources>>data folder of gatling project,that solved the problem

```
package simulations

import baseConfig.BaseSimulation
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._

import scala.language.postfixOps

class ERBSGetServiceVersion extends BaseSimulation {


  val httpProtocol = http
    .baseURL("http://r21sVCS.onlinegaming.local:4059/Business/")

  val header = Map(
    "POST" -> "http://r21sVCS.onlinegaming.local:4059/Business/EventReporterV2 HTTP/1.1",
    "Accept-Encoding" -> "gzip,deflate",
    "Content-Type" -> "text/xml;charset=UTF-8",
    "SOAPAction" -> "http://www.ds.com/Service/2013-03/IEventReporterEndpoint/GetAccountVersion",
    "Content-Length" -> "385",
    "Host" -> "r21sVCS.onlinegaming.local:4059",
    "Connection" -> "Keep-Alive",
    "User-Agent" -> "Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)"
    )






  val scn = scenario("SOAPRecordedSimulation")
    .exec(http("Get Service Soap Request")
      .post("EventReporterV2")
      .headers(header)
      .body(ElFileBody("Soap_request_0000.txt")))
  setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(20))).protocols(httpProtocol)


}
```